# Condition in laravel 5 Middleware always false

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-middleware

I'm  trying to give condition in my `Middleware`.

> Here is my script

```
if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->type == 'TP001') {
    $menu->add("User Control",array('nickname' => "user",'class'=>'treeview'))
    ->append(' <b class="caret"></b>')
    ->prepend('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> ');

    $menu->user->add('Daftar User','user/list');
    $menu->user->add('Tipe User','user/type');
} else {
    /* Some code here...*/
}
```

The script above I cants see the menu with the condition even I already login with `'TP001'` (always in else), then I try to fix my code with this

```
auth()->user()->isDeveloper()
```

> My model

```
public function isDeveloper()
{
    return ($this->type == 'TP001');
}
```

But still not working, is there any way to give the condition like above but in a correct way? Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

> My Kernel

```
  protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Frontend::class,
  ];
```

Comment: Where is your `auth()->user()->type`? Does `type` exists? Show me your `dd(auth()->user());` I might help

Comment: @vietnguyen09 I get null when i try `dd(auth()->user())` in middleware but when i try it in my controller it show me the array things

Comment: So it is clearly that your condition can't not work because your `auth()->user()` is null. And now problem is how to getting `auth()->user()` in middleware?

Comment: you can get user with Auth::user() Facade.

Comment: i have add this `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` but still not working

Comment: @vietnguyen09 any solutions ?

Comment: How/Where is your middleware registered? You need to make sure this middleware runs *after* the middleware that checks the session and loads the current authenticated user.

Comment: Are you get `auth()->user()` when you use `dd()`??

Comment: @HirenGohel I get `null`

Comment: @Cryode I put it in my kernel right ?

Comment: So, first you need to check why it give you null! Are you checking this after user login??

Comment: I don't know how to check it. Becuase i'm new then when i check it in my controller i get the value

Comment: If you check it in controller and if you got the current user, then you also send it to blade file using `with()` OR you can check it using `Auth::check()`. Try this and let me know what happened?

Comment: I do this `{{ Auth::user()->name }}` and i can get it . sorry for my bad English

Comment: Ok, no problem. So, now you can check it like this: `if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->type == 'TP001') {` Let me know if this work! If this is not in script and in simple code, then you need to use `@if`

Comment: @HirenGohel in my view ? or middleware ?

Comment: Obviously in your `view` where you use `if` condition!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149678/discussion-between-yvs1102-and-hiren-gohel).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The middleware kernel has that `$middleware` you posted, with middleware that run in every request, but they run before the route middleware (which you select in the routes definition).

You are probably using the "web" middleware group. Try adding your custom middleware at the end. I think the default in Laravel 5.4 is:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Frontend::class, // <-- your middleware at the end
    ],
    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

This way you know your middleware will run after the others (the one that starts the session and checks authentication)

Answer (score 3):

You can put your custom middleware in protected $routeMiddleware = [ ] array in kernel file like this

```
$routeMiddleWare = ['frontend' => \App\Http\Middleware\Frontend::class]
```

After this you will be able to access your Auth::check
and don't forget to put

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['frontend']], function() { // your routes will go here.. });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get current user in any blade file like this:

`{{ Auth::user()->name }}`

In your blade do this:

```
@if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->type == 'TP001')
     /* Some code here...*/
@endif
```

In your middleware do this as per your requirement!:

```
if (\Auth::check() && \Auth::user()->type == 'TP001') { 
     $menu->add("User Control",array('nickname' => "user",'class'=>'treeview')) 
    ->append(' <b class="caret"></b>') 
    ->prepend('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> '); 

    $menu->user->add('Daftar User','user/list'); 
    $menu->user->add('Tipe User','user/type'); 
    } else { 
       /* Some code here...*/ 
}
```